# Reactjs JwtToken is not being stored

Tags: reactjs, jwt

We have a web application project that has jwtToken for login. my problem is that my device removes token when refreshed.

I already used different browsers but it still the same. The same project works on my other team's device and I'm the only one that does this kind of problem.

This is my jwtToken.js

```js
const jwtToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
    // Create Jwt token
    const token = user.getJwtToken();

    // Options for cookie
    const options = {
        expires: new Date(
            Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES_TIME * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        ),
httpOnly: true
    }
    res.status(statusCode).cookie('token', token, options).json({
        success: true,
        token,
        user
    })

}

module.exports = jwtToken;
```

This is my login Function at the controller

```js
exports.loginUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // Checks if email and password is entered by user
    if (!email || !password) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Please enter email & password', 400))
    }
    const user = await User.findOne({email }).select('+password')

    if (!user) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Invalid Credentials', 401));
    }

    else if (user.status == "deactive" ) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Account is on Hold!', 401));
    }

    // Checks if password is correct or not
    const isPasswordMatched = await user.comparePassword(password);

    if (!isPasswordMatched) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Invalid Email or Password', 401));
    }
    sendToken(user, 200, res)
}
```

Comment: How do you store the token?

Comment: where the "token" is stored in the browser ?

Comment: Please include some relevant code so that community memebers can give better answers nor they might  make guesses which might not be what you are looking for

Comment: This is my jwtToken.js 
`const jwtToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {`
    `const token = user.getJwtToken();`
    `const options = {`
        `expires: new Date(`
            `Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES_TIME * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`
        `),`
`httpOnly: true`
    `}`
    `res.status(statusCode).cookie('token', token, options).json({`
        `success: true,`
        `token,`
        `user`
    `})`
`}`
`module.exports = jwtToken;`

which then being called on the controller when logging in

Comment: @Azzy, I've already edited my post. Thank you for guidance.